# Relative layout disappears both views when setting right and left properties on both

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have the below layout right now in my RelativeLayout

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button"
    android:hint="Whatsup!"
    android:padding="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/text"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/text"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_black_off"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

This makes my ImageView to be of size 80dp, and the left side of it is filled with EditText.

Now if I add a property "android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text"", then both my views disappear? Why's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of circular dependency. Your views are depending on each other to place themselves on the screen.

Your `EditText` is already dependent on `ImageView` by `android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"` Now when you add `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text"` your `ImageView` depends on `EditText` it becomes circular. which is not allowed.

If you look in the studio Just below "Design" tab there will be red exclamation. click on that & you'll see following error.

[image: Circular dependency]